# Monte Carlo approach to RAN bonds in Quantlib or suggestions

Tags: programming, monte-carlo, floating-rate

This is a problem from Schlogl's book in the chapter on the HJM model:

Price option of the RAN instrument with 3 month coupons and maturity 3 years using Monte Carlo([Exercise 4 Range Accrual Note](http://www.schlogl.com/sites/default/files/Chapter8exercises.pdf)).

Is the code in the Quantlib library? If so can you tell me its location, thank you.
If not can you give me some suggestions on how to approach it.

**The background**

A bond's value and payoff are of the form:

$$V=\sum_{i}^{N} c_{i} B(T_{i-1},T_{i}) \text{ and } [V-K]^{+},$$
where K is the strike, $c_{i}$ are the coupons and $B(T_{i-1},T_{i})$ is the price of a zero bond at time $T_{i-1}$ with maturity $T_{i+1}$.

In the FRN the coupons $c_{i}$ are determined by some asset or floating rate. Specifically in R
AN with 3-month coupons (90 days) and interest compounded daily we have:

$$c_{i}=\bar{r}\frac{1}{90}\sum_{k=90\cdot i}^{90\cdot (i+1)}L(t_{k},t_{k+1}),$$

where the Libor rate is $L(t_{k},t_{k+1})=\frac{1}{t_{k+1}-t_{k+1}}(\frac{1}{B(t_{k},t_{k+1})}-1)$ and $\bar{r}$ is a fixed number or the Libor rate plus a spread s.

So we are searching to price the option with payoff $(\sum_{i}^{N} c_{i} B(T_{i-1},T_{i})-K)^{+}$ with the above $c_{i}$.

Glasserman in his Monte Carlo book section 3.7, describes how to go about the Libor rate option. I will try that as well.